# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError when loading .dll

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface

I am trying to use a public interface in a .dll file in JAVA. This is what a public interface in the .dll shows:

```
// Interface declaration.
public interface ISslTcpClient
{
    string Encrypt(string requestContent);
    string Decrypt(string requestContent);        
};
```

Here is how I load my dll and use it in my Java application in eclipse:

```
public class NJInew {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("ICVTnsClient");
    }

    native String Encrypt(String requestContent);

    public static void main(String[] args) {      
        NJInew p= new NJInew ();
        p.Encrypt("pejman");

    }
```

}
However I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: NJInew.Encrypt(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
at NJInew.Encrypt(Native Method)
at NJInew.main(NJInew.java:13)
```

Please let me know how to fix this issue and I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: It can't find whatever you're calling.

Comment: if I just use  static {
   System.loadLibrary("ICVTnsClient");
 }    it works. I tried changing the name from ICVTnsClient to some wrong name to see if it gives me error and it did give an execption. The problem arise when I try to use the Encrypt method from the interface

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand how the native DLL can possibly look like a Java interface. Are you sure it's a JNI DLL? You can't call any old DLL from Java. If it isn't a JNI DLL you'll either need to add the required JNI entry points to it, starting with the `javah` tool, or write a wrapper DLL that contains those and calls this one.

Comment: I have the final dll in hand. I don't have the actual code that was used in generating that dll. Do you think maybe I should write a C# code (I think the dll is in C#) to use the methods in that dll then create an additional dll that works with my JAVA be a good idea?

Comment: In that case you must have have changed the Java code to disagree with the native code. Different package, class name, or method names. Revert.

Comment: Thanks for your help. To answer your second question, the interface I was referring to is the interface in the C# dll. The documentation of the DLL says use these interfaces. This dll is made to be used in a C# code, but I am trying to use it in our JAVA application. Does the C# code need to be altered to be JNI compatible?

Comment: Yes, or do what you said in your comment above: make a JNI DLL that calls this one, starting with the `javah` step. You can't call any old DLL directly from Java.

Answer (score 0):

This interface looks definitely like written in .NET C#. Therefore you do not need to call native DLL but managed .NET DLL and that is completely different topic.

You can achieve it yourself by wrapping .NET DLL with native C++ code and calling it from JAVA but number of obstacles and challenges is huge... You need to take care of type conversion, memory management, threads, C++ runtime depndencies and more... so that approach is not recommended.

What you should look for is native bridge like Javonet which takes care of all those things for you and makes sure you can run your code on any machine.

Using your interface would like like this:

```
Javonet.addReference("ICVTnsClient.dll");

NObject client = Javonet.New("SslTcpClient"); 
//some concreto type which implements this interface

String encryptedStr = client.invoke("Encrypt", "some string");
```

You can get free license for academic and non-commercial usage or try the free trial: http://www.javonet.com